What is the -iv- part in the word interconnectivity?
I'm writing a term thesis (I don't really know, if that is the correct way to name it, since I'm not from an English-speaking country), where I need to analyse a literary text. In the analysis there is a task to make a derivational analysis of one multisyllable word. I chose the word interconnectivity and made such an analysis:

Interconnectivity

Interconnected + -ity = adj. + -ity (acridity, adversity)
Interconnect + -ed = v. + -ed (spelled, closed)
Inter- + connect = inter- + v. (interchange, interlace)


3 cuts, 4 ICs

And then, when I wanted to divide the word into constituents, I came across a problem which arose
a question. What is the -iv- part in this word? Is it a suffix? I know that inter- is a prefix, -connect- is a root and -ity is a suffix. But what is -iv-?
And how did it appear in this word? Is it some sort of change from -ed to -iv-?

act - interact - interactive* - interactivity*

-ive is a suffix used to make adjectives from verbs like: interconnect -> interconnective  from which interconnect+iv+ity:

word-forming element making adjectives from verbs, meaning "pertaining to, tending to; doing, serving to do," in some cases from Old French -if, but usually directly from Latin adjectival suffix -ivus.

(Etymoline)

It seems to be a general principle in English that you keep adding more suffixes and don't remove existing ones first, hence reflexivity, directionality, proportionality, intentionality, and interconnectivity.

@StuartF - I don’t think it is an English attitude, the same rule applies to other European languages such  as French, Spanish etc. we should probably blame Latin.
